# Nginx as reverse proxy to specific path

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, jenkins

I'm trying to set up Nginx as a reverse proxy for Jenkins CI/CD.

A very popular plugin for Jenkins, Blue Ocean, is accessible at `<jenkins-domain.tld>/blue`.

I'm looking for a Nginx configuration that allows me to use a separate domain to access Blue Ocean, i.e. `<jenkins-domain.tld>` and `<blue-ocean-domain.tld>`. So all requests to `<blue-ocean-domain.tld>` should be routed to the `/blue` subpath.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use so called [server_blocks](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/)

```
upstream jenkins {
  server jenkins:8080 fail_timeout=10;
}

server {
  listen       ...;
  server_name  jenkins-domain.tld;

  location / {                
    proxy_redirect          http:// https://;
    proxy_pass              http://jenkins;
  }
}

server {
  listen       ...;
  server_name  blue-ocean-domain.tld;

  location / {                
    proxy_redirect          http:// https://;
    proxy_pass              http://jenkins/blue;
  }
}
```